# How to insert single document to multiple collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have model class as shown below

```
@Document(collection = "SAMPLE")
public class SampleData {
@Id
private long id;
private Map<String,String> meta;
private List<CheckList> checkList;
}
```

Now i want to insert data into two collections "SAMPLE" and "TEST".
Is there any possibility to do that without creating another model class with @Document(collection="TEST")

Comment: No there is not, need to do that in your application.

Comment: @krishna, I am also looking for the same. Did you fine any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no possibility to do that.
the only solution could be looping.

```
db.collection('collection name').findAndModify(
            { "_id": ObjectId(req.body.id) },
            [],
            { $set: { "delete": req.body.delete } },
            { new: true },
            function (err, data123) {
                if (err) throw err;
                db.collection('collection name').findAndModify(
                    { "_id": ObjectId(req.body.error_id) },
                    [],
                    { $set: { "read": true } },
                    { new: true },
                    function (err, data1234) {
                        if (err) throw err;

                        res.write(JSON.stringify(data1234.value));
                        res.end();
                        db.close();
                    });
            });
```

it is possible to fetch data from more than 1 collection using mongodb aggregate (lookup).
[Click here for more info](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: You mean that I want to loop on every promise ?

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, insert operations target a single collection.

Read more on their documentation here.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/#create-operations